# No APIs published on the store in clustered mode - wso2 api manager 2.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am deployed Clustered API Manager 2.0.0 installation with five VMs:

**VM1**
shared key manager + analytics node:

- Dedicated key manager running with /var/wso2am/bin/wso2server.sh -Dprofile=api-key-manager
- wso2am analytics running with default port offset (+1) by /var/wso2am-analytics/bin/wso2server.sh

**VM2**

dedicated gateway node running with default offset (+0) by /var/wso2am/bin/wso2server.sh -Dprofile=gateway-manager

**VM3**

dedicated store node running with default offset (+0) by /var/wso2am/var/wso2am/bin/wso2server.sh -Dprofile=api-store

**VM4**

dedicated traffic manager node running with default offset (+0) by /var/wso2am/bin/wso2server.sh -Dprofile=traffic-manager

**VM5**

dedicated publisher node running with default offset (+0) by /var/wso2am/bin/wso2server.sh -Dprofile=api-publisher

I completed all steps in [Clustering API Manager 2.0.0](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+2.0.0)

I setup two cluster nodes with VM3 and VM5, and I see /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata registry on both store and publisher nodes.
I also can browse APIs created in publisher node  on store carbon admin interface (metadata->list>APIs)

But there no APIs appear in the dedicated store frond end on VM3 ("VM3/store").

In the same time if I will open "VM5/store" page on publisher node, I am can to see published API just fine

What should I check?

**UPD:**

The APIs is pushed to the store node with wrong Lifecycle Status "created" that is not updated accordingly. I tried to change Lifecycle Status manually on the store node and API is published on store mode just fine.

So seems issue is with Lifecycle Status live update to the store node. How can I fix it?

**UPD2:**

Here is my axis2.xml config on store (ip is x.x.x.15)

```
   <clustering class="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent"
                enable="true">
   <parameter name="membershipScheme">wka</parameter>
   <parameter name="domain">wso2.carbon.domain</parameter>
   <parameter name="localMemberHost">x.x.x.15</parameter>
   <parameter name="localMemberPort">4000</parameter>
        <members>
            <member>
                <hostName>x.x.x.17</hostName>
                <port>4000</port>
            </member>
            <member>
                <hostName>x.x.x.15</hostName>
                <port>4000</port>
            </member>            
        </members>
```

`

Here is my axis2.xml config on publisher (ip is x.x.x.17)

```
    <clustering class="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent"
                enable="true">
   <parameter name="membershipScheme">wka</parameter>
   <parameter name="domain">wso2.carbon.domain</parameter>
   <parameter name="localMemberHost">x.x.x.17</parameter>
   <parameter name="localMemberPort">4000</parameter>

        <members>
            <member>
                <hostName>x.x.x.15</hostName>
                <port>4000</port>
            </member>
            <member>
                <hostName>x.x.x.17</hostName>
                <port>4000</port>
            </member>            
        </members>
```

messages in store log file

```
   Cluster domain: wso2.carbon.domain
   Loading hazelcast configuration from axis2 clustering configuration
   Using wka based membership management scheme
   Added member: Host:x.x.x.17, Remote Host:null, Port: 4000, HTTP:-1, HTTPS:-1, Domain: null, Sub-domain:null, Active:true
   Added member: Host:x.x.x.15, Remote Host:null, Port: 4000, HTTP:-1, HTTPS:-1, Domain: null, Sub-domain:null, Active:true
   Hazelcast initialized in 9167ms
   Local member: [3c9c1b66-9ad9-4e4f-8d7e-de2864e8d56d] - Host:x.x.x.15, Remote Host:null, Port: 4000, HTTP:8280, HTTPS:8243, Domain: wso2.carbon.domain, Sub-domain:worker, Active:true
   Cluster initialization completed
   Task service starting in CLUSTERED mode...
   Successfully Initialized Eventing on Registry
```

messages in publisher log file

```
Cluster domain: wso2.carbon.domain
Loading hazelcast configuration from axis2 clustering configuration
Using wka based membership management scheme
Added member: Host:x.x.x.15, Remote Host:null, Port: 4000, HTTP:-1, HTTPS:-1, Domain: null, Sub-domain:null, Active:true
Added member: Host:x.x.x.17, Remote Host:null, Port: 4000, HTTP:-1, HTTPS:-1, Domain: null, Sub-domain:null, Active:true
Hazelcast initialized in 10380ms
Local member: [094f544b-1cfe-41b1-9a5f-0664aefc1ba5] - Host:x.x.x.17, Remote Host:null, Port: 4000, HTTP:8280, HTTPS:8243, Domain: wso2.carbon.domain, Sub-domain:worker, Active:true
Cluster initialization completed
Error in instantiating class : org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtThrottleUsageHandler
Sequence Deployment from the file : /var/wso2am/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/_throttle_out_handler_.xml : Failed.
Deployment of the Synapse Artifact from file : /var/wso2am/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/_throttle_out_handler_.xml : Failed!
The file has been backed up into : NO_BACKUP_ON_WORKER.INFO
Deployment of synapse artifact failed. Error reading /var/wso2am/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/_throttle_out_handler_.xml : Sequence Deployment from the file : /var/wso2am/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/_throttle_out_handler_.xml : Failed.
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: Sequence Deployment from the file : /var/wso2am/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/_throttle_out_handler_.xml : Failed.
Error in instantiating class : org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtFaultHandler
Sequence Deployment from the file : /var/wso2am/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/fault.xml : Failed.
Deployment of the Synapse Artifact from file : /var/wso2am/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/fault.xml : Failed!
The file has been backed up into : NO_BACKUP_ON_WORKER.INFO
Deployment of synapse artifact failed. Error reading /var/wso2am/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/fault.xml : Sequence Deployment from the file : /var/wso2am/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/fault.xml : Failed.
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: Sequence Deployment from the file : /var/wso2am/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/fault.xml : Failed.
Task service starting in CLUSTERED mode...
Successfully Initialized Eventing on Registry
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 reasons for this.

1) Using hostnames in `<localMemberHost>` and `<members>` sections in axis2.xml. Use IPs instead.

2) Not having the same value in store and publisher for `<parameter name="domain">wso2.carbon.domain</parameter>` in axis2.xml

**Update**: 
Attached configurations look fine. So another possibility is that this is a registry indexing problem. For that you can try reindexing.

Update `<lastAccessTimeLocation>` value of `registry.xml` in store node like this, and restart the server.

```
<lastAccessTimeLocation>/_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing/lastaccesstime2</lastAccessTimeLocation>
```

Comment: I have updated topic with configs and logs, May you point me a possible mistake?

Comment: where is a settings in `registry.xml' 


<remoteInstance url="https://***"> 

What this url should be pointed to?

Should I put local IP with 9443 port, or should I put public dns name with 443 port (I have reverse NGINX on front)?

Comment: In your case `remoteInstance` value is not used.